# set define off verify off not working in flyway

Tags: oracle, flyway

```
SQL State : 42000
Error Code : 922
Message : ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
Line : 1
Statement : set define off verify off feedback off
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode rollback
```

I am trying to migrate a oracle script with flyway version 6.5.1 However I am not able to do so as the error is.If I remove this line then the script starts executing further.

Comment: Those are `sqlplus` commands **not** SQL commands and cannot be used outside of `sqlplus` (and don't really make sense outside of it)

Comment: I am trying to migrate them. Please check this issue https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2257

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name is saying, those are sqlplus settings. You use define off to avoid that if the sql command contains & is treated as input variable. That happens when you run a script and the content contains such character.  Verify controls whether to display the lines after substitution. Change your sql script or execute it by sqlplus

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I understand that. My script does contains &. Also did you check the link.

Comment: @PeaceIsPearl , are you using Flyway to migrate or to install an apex application ? I saw the github page and it has an apex installation script

Comment: @RobertoHernandez   I have given that link for reference. I am facing similar issue. Not sure about the script there

Comment: @PeaceIsPearl, sorry I have no experience with Flyway. I hope someone can help you

Comment: Is it community edition or pro?

Comment: @Kumar it is enterprise edition 6.5.1. Is it possible that the fixes pushed in community edition are not available in enterprise edition?

Comment: @PeaceIsPearl Fixes are pushed first to commercial versions.Did you set `flyway.oracle.sqlplus=true` in configuration otherwise you need to contact their support

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this with Oracle 11 and the migration will succeed if you set

`flyway.oracle.sqlplus=true`

in your configuration (or one of the other configuration methods; command line arg, environment variable, Java API). This option must be set true if you intend to use any SQL*Plus commands.